# How can i access and change properties of grandchildren elements with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create small boxes inside boxes as shown below in the image, but cant seem to move anything inside the flexbox-item elements, I have come as far as creating the parent and children elements but the issue is manipulating the grandchildren elements as i want them in different positions. I'm very new to this so i'm definitely doing something wrong... any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

[image: What im trying to do...>]

```css
/* Parent container */
.flexbox-container{  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.flexbox-square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

/* Child */
.flexbox-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

/*Flexbox Items*/

.flexbox-item-1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-2 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    align-self: auto;
}

.flexbox-item-3 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-4 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-5 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-6 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-7 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-8 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="flexbox-container">
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1"> 
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-1"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2"> 
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-4">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-4"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-5">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-5"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-6">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-6"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-7">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-7"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-8">  
                <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just use flexbox on the `flexbox-item ` elements and then adjust the contents as desired. Flexbox is not inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mainly all `justify-content` and `align-items` but i kept it all with flexbox per your question. You can also use positionings.

```css
/* Parent container */
.flexbox-container{  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox-square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

/* Child */
.flexbox-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

/*Flexbox Items*/

.flexbox-item-1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item-2 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-item-3 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-item-4 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-item-5 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.flexbox-item-6 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-item-7 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-item-8 {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-square-7 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flexbox-square-8 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1"> 
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2"> 
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-4">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-5">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-5"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-6">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-6"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-7">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-7"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-8">  
        <div class="flexbox-square flexbox-square-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was targeting the wrong element this whole time... created extra div classes when i didnt need to, i realize that now :) thank you so much!!

Comment: @jujuju199 no problem! take care